# How to transfer conversation from Bot to human agents? in ibm watson using node js

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have created watson chat bot which answers users FAQ's using Node js as a middle ware. but how can i transfer the conversation from bot to any human agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you need to know: Watson Conversation Service is one endpoint API, so, you can call the service and creates one condition in your backend for identifying if the user wants to be attended for one's Human Agents or anything that you want to do with yours application.

For example, you can see the Project by IBM Developer's inside Watson Developer Cloud called [conversation-simple](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple) using Node.js.

You can simply create one `#intent` condition in your chatbot likes:

```
if bot recognizes #wantsHumanAgent
response: Do you want to talk with one Professional?
```

And creates one `@entity` with the `values`: yes or no, after it, try to create one child node with the condition:

```
if bot recognizes @yesOrNo:yes
response: Please wait! I'll pass you on to an attendant.
```

Or you can add the link for the user's talks with the Attendant too, like:

```
if bot recognizes @yesOrNo:yes
response: The link to talk with one Attendent is <a  target="_blank" href="https://yourlink.com">Talk to one Professional!</a>.<br/><br/>
```

**Obs.:** You can add one *custom code* to creates your `functions` or *do something* in your application using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725072/how-do-i-add-an-action-to-watson-conversation-response/42725475#42725475) as a base, and creates one custom code for what you want: Add in your chat one option to talk with Human Agents.

**Note.:** This is just some's suggestions to use based on good practices. You need to guide your user in your Virtual Assistant for one better Attendance.

- See more [examples](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html#dialog-build) to build with Watson Conversation Service.

Comment: hey thanx sayuri for the help i understood the above solution but can i transfer my bot chat history to the facebook messenger api ?