# How to integrate Facebook with Watson conversation

Tags: facebook, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I can already connect my conversation to my Facebook page and the bot is working.
My Problem is that i couldn't find a single tutorial on how to make calls to a server that is owned by a company and has information about accounts and payments, for example when i type to the Chat-bot that i want to see a list of accounts, the chat-bot would reply with a list from that API; Or i can login to that server with my account by typing the account's name and password in the chat-bot. I just wanted to know if anyone knows how to do that or if its even possible or knows a tutorial that explains it. I also would prefer if the tutorial was detailed because i'm  new to this field.

Comment: Here is the app architecture and how to use the conversation service with that. You need an app as middleware: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/index.html#how-to-use-the-service

Comment: You mean something like botkit? i already used that to connect to facebook. I just dont know how i can use it to reach the backend system, and i couldnt find tutorials for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Felipe Paixao said, you need to develop an orchestrating application.
I've found one example that explains step-by-step how to use Watson Conversation with Facebook Messenger.

**Requirements:**

- Facebook page
- IBM Bluemix
- A Facebook [Developer](https://developers.facebook.com) Account
- [Source code](https://github.com/sayurimizuguchi/conversation-with-facebook).

**Step - IBM Bluemix:**

- Create a SDK for Node.js application
- Create a Watson Conversation service
- Create your Workspace for Watson Conversation and build your Dialog
- Configure the JS app and integrate it with the Watson Service *Connections* -> *Connect Existent*:

In your App created in IBM Bluemix, access the Tools and go to IDE Eclipse, and create a new file: `app.js` with [this code](https://github.com/sayurimizuguchi/conversation-with-facebook/blob/master/app.js).

Replace with your credentials the [username](https://github.com/sayurimizuguchi/conversation-with-facebook/blob/master/app.js#L19) and [password](https://github.com/sayurimizuguchi/conversation-with-facebook/blob/master/app.js#L20)

You can see your credentials inside Service Credentials, or going to your workspace and access:

[image]

**Step - Facebook Developers:**

- Enter to facebook developers with your Facebook account
- In the Dashboard select *Create a New App* and Select *Messenger*
- Put the URL from your Bluemix (Now IBM Cloud) app and select the options marked: `messages`, `message_deliveries`, `messaging_options` e `messaging_postbacks`.
- Now, return to our app to configure the `app.js` [file](https://github.com/sayurimizuguchi/conversation-with-facebook/blob/master/app.js#L28) with our new FB `token` autogenerated and deploy it.

**Step Final**

Test your chatbot: If you made everything OK, we will have your chatbot available on your Facebook page.

**Obs.:** For built your example, you can add the lines of code for call your API in the `app.js` using the `http` module, using the Advanced JSON in Watson Conversation and create one "action": "callApi", and recognize with your code for do something, like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725072/how-do-i-add-an-action-to-watson-conversation-response/42725475#42725475).

- See the [Official Reference](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-create-a-chatbot-in-facebook-messenger/) that I used to build Facebook Messenger with Node.js SDK (Back-end) source code based on Priscila Parodi codes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to develop an orchestrating application, that would be responsible to connect the IBM Watson Conversation with your desired Fronted, Facebook in this case, and the Backend systems. I imagine that you are using the automatic deploy to Facebook from the Conversation Tooling, this option would not resolve your need to access a Backend.

The image passed by @data_henrik shows exactly that.

In conversation, you can create context variables that will be used as triggers in the Orchestrator to let him know when you need to call a Backend service to provide an information and then write the response into the Conversation context.

About using the Chatbot to login into a system, passing a password, this isn't a safe option since all information typed would go to Watson Conversation log and any person with access to the tooling/api could see the passwords.