# Connecting My IBM Watson Chatbot to Facebook Messanger Ads

Tags: facebook, chatbot

My brother built a chatbot through IBM Watson and we want to use it for Facebook Messenger ads.

Has anyone tried connecting their IBM Watson bot to Messenger ads?

I tried copying the JSON code into the Facebook message setup on the ad but that didn't work. I am thinking I need to set up Bot Payload or a webhook but I haven't exactly figured that out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the Facebook Messenger API?  What have you tried?  You should probably also review their ToS, this sounds like something that might violate it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to integrate facebook with Watson conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152239/how-to-make-calls-to-own-server-api-in-watson-conversation)

Comment: There is this. https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/cognitive-advertising