# Chatbot - Possible to call Watson API to respond user queries?

Tags: nlp, ibm-watson, chatbot

Chatbot has been developed using IBM bulemix to respond the user queries of grade one students.

Suppose a question raised "What is the life cycle of the leaf?" As of now, Chatbot has no entities related to leaf, life cycle etc..

Chatbot identifies the above query as an irrelevant entity. For the above case is it possible call any Watson knowledge API to answer the above queries?

Or

Can we make any third party searches (google/bing).

Or

the only option we need teach more relevant entities to the chatbot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rabindra said, you can use Discovery. IBM Developers built one example using Conversation and Discovery service using [Java](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-with-discovery). And I built one example using [Node.js](https://github.com/sayurimizuguchi/conversation-with-discovery) based on the Conversation simple example. You can read the README and will understand how it works.

Basically, you need to know: this example has one [`action variable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725072/how-do-i-add-an-action-to-watson-conversation-response/42725475#42725475) to call for Discovery when don't have the "relevant information" for an answer to the user and the Discovery service is called for get relevant answers.

You can see more about [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SasXUqBE-38) from Official IBM Watson channel.

- See more about [Discovery Service](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/index.html).
- See the [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/) for using Discovery Service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Watson-Discovery Tool 
https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/discovery/

Answer (score 0):

You can also check entity linking service from Bing: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/entity-linking-intelligence-service/. It is in preview for now, so you will get limited queries per second but it is free for use.