# IBM WATSON - Upload json file to create meaningful intents

Tags: json, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

My requirement is,

I have an exam schedule data for a class of students, And I want to create a **Chat bot Teaching Assistant(TA)** with this data source and to respond to the students, Example - Student asks, when is my next exam , Then TA has to respond the date time of his/her next exam.

So what is the recommended solution?

So my assumption is to upload the exam schedule as json document in a preferred format and take use accordingly.

Am I correct or not? If not, can you help me suggesting the best option to do this?

***Note*** - Exam schedule is dynamic which can be updated by the admin whenever he wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you need to send the correct data, but, Watson Conversation will give you the possibility for built one awesome Assistant with his Natural Language power. And you need to add some custom codes for integrates APIs, get database data, use Webservices, etc. Watson in your application will be one endpoint, and you can do a lot of thins with code.

**Example:**

- After create your chatbot, when you user asks about "When is my next exam" in the *Child node*, you'll create one [`ACTION VARIABLE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725072/how-do-i-add-an-action-to-watson-conversation-response/42725475#42725475) for call another service with some custom code... and in your backend when you `post` some **message**, this value from this action variable will `return` in your `response` parameter, and you'll can `doSomething()`, like get the exam data. You can click in my link above for understand how these action variable and context variables work.

So, like you said, the data can update, what you can do so is use *Webservices*, if you Univeristy have some Web application, so in the function `doSomething()` you'll `POST` and use the webservice to return the *correct* exam data, and return for your user like my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725072/how-do-i-add-an-action-to-watson-conversation-response/42725475#42725475).

- [Example for Integrate some API](https://github.com/doconnor78/conversation-simple-weather) using Conversation: Weather API.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing with my application. I had a similar requirement where I need to fetch specific info from the database depending on a specific triggered node in Conversation.

Comment: @Sayuri Mizuguchi. Thanks dude.