# Having troubles understanding how IBM Watson could interact with my Android Studio project

Tags: android-studio, chatbot, ibm-watson

this is a basic/rookie question, and is something I've been scouring the web for in the past few days. I am trying to create an application that will have a built in chatbot. I would like for, for example if the user says 
"hey, can you take me to the home screen" for the chatbot to do so. In essence, I know how to make the bot have a conversation using intents/entities, but I have no idea how I can make the bot interact with Android studio since i'm doing all that in the workspace. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: this help? https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk

Comment: Otherwise it is just a rest API. You can find sample calls in the API docs.

Comment: hi Simon, thank you for your reply! I'll check out the ink and see if it helps :)
I'm trying to save context variables so I can use it eslewhere, I'm sorry if I'm not making much sense!

Comment: Hi @KarimTimer, here is one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42725072/how-do-i-add-an-action-to-watson-conversation-response/42725475#42725475) about context variables and how to get in your backend.